# How to make a string blink for a specified time using the colored function in the termcolor module? [Python 2.7]

Tags: python, python-2.7, termcolor

I am trying to figure out how I can use the `blink` attribute of the `colored()` function in the termcolor module to blink for a specific amount of time, and then stop.

I looked at the package index and the properties of this, but I haven't seen anywhere describing if this would be possible.

I currently have the following bit of code that makes the string blink indefinitely:

```
print(colored('Picking the first dealer by random...', 'cyan', attrs=['blink']))
```

I would like to be able to make this string blink for a couple of seconds, stop, and then continue running the program. Is there a possible way to do this?

Comment: You would need to write the blinking text to the terminal, then erase it and replace it with non-blinking text – there is no support in terminals for modifiers that expire after some time, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This   `blink_once()`   function will show the word TEXT for .5 secs and will hide it for .5 secs afterwards.

So the effect is just a one time blink. I do it writing spaces in he same place as the text after a delay. It's easy to modify the delay or the text, or adding them as parameters if you need it for your specific project.

The `blink(number)` calls `blink_once()` a determined `number` of times.  So `blink(3)` will show the word "TEXT" blinking 3 times.

```
 import sys
 import time

 def blink_once():
     sys.stdout.write('\rTEXT')
     time.sleep(0.5)
     b = ("Loading")
     sys.stdout.write('\r     ')
     time.sleep(0.5)

def blink(number):
     for x in range(0,number):
         blink_once()

blink(3)
```

Comment: The string more than 4 characters is not working i.e it is blinking only 4 characters as if, if the word is StackOverflow, then only stac is blinking KOVerflow is not.